# Can UIWebViews create and access HTML5 databases?

Tags: javascript, iphone, html

I've built an online web app using HTML5 databases and it works fine in Mobile Safari. However, when I view the same site in a UIWebView inside an app, the HTML5 database part of the app doesn't appear to be working. Am I doing something wrong? It seems logical that something inside a UIWebView should be able to create HTML5 databases, but maybe I'm wrong... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well I figured out what the problem is... UIWebViews are limited just like Mobile Safari to a database size of 5 mb max. However, unlike Mobile Safari, if the requested database size is over 5 mb it simply quits, whereas Mobile Safari asks you if you would like to continue anyways.